# Replacing entire body using HTMX

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I have the following `index.html`

```php-template
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.5"></script>
</head>
<body id="bomb-main" class="main-page">
<div class="bomb"
     hx-trigger="click"
     hx-swap="outerHTML"
     hx-target="#bomb-main"
     hx-get="/boom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`/boom` returns the following response

```php-template
<body id="bomb-main" class="bomb-animation">
<h1>ka-boom</h1>
</body>
```

On clicking , the body is replaced but the class remains same.

```php-template
<body id="bomb-main" class="main-page">
<h1>ka-boom</h1>
</body>
```

How to change the class of the `body`?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/

Comment: looks like body is never changed, even if you attach hx-attributes to the body tag itself: https://jsfiddle.net/zgt98d3n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to replace the `body` element. `htmx` converts the `outerHTML` to `innerHTML` swap value. See the notes on `hx-swap` [documentation](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap/)

> Due to DOM limitations, it’s not possible to use the outerHTML method on the `<body>` element. htmx will change outerHTML on `<body>` to use innerHTML